# Spark-Scala : Create split rows based on the value of other column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an Input as below

| id | size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |

output - If input is 4 (size column) split 4 times(1-4) and if input size column value is 2 split it
1-2 times.

| id | size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array of sequence from 1 to `size` using `sequence` function and then to explode it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq((1,4), (2,2)).toDF("id", "size")
df
  .withColumn("size", explode(sequence(lit(1), col("size"))))
  .show(false)
```

The output would be:

```
+---+----+
|id |size|
+---+----+
|1  |1   |
|1  |2   |
|1  |3   |
|1  |4   |
|2  |1   |
|2  |2   |
+---+----+
```

Comment: Ooooh nice, I didn't know about the `sequence` function! Better than my proposal, upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your `size` column into an incrementing sequence using `Seq.range` and then explode the arrays. Something like this:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, col}

// Original dataframe
val df = Seq((1,4), (2,2)).toDF("id", "size")

// Mapping over this dataframe: turning each row into (idx, array)
val df_with_array = df
  .map(row => {
    (row.getInt(0), Seq.range(1, row.getInt(1) + 1)) 
  })
  .toDF("id", "array")
  .select(col("id"), explode(col("array")))

output.show()
+---+---+
| id|col|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  4|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  2|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use first use sequence function to create sequence from 1 to size and then explode it.

```
val df = input.withColumn("seq", sequence(lit(1), $"size"))
df.show()
+---+----+------------+
| id|size|         seq|
+---+----+------------+
|  1|   4|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|  2|   2|      [1, 2]|
+---+----+------------+

df.withColumn("size", explode($"seq")).drop("seq").show()
+---+----+
| id|size|
+---+----+
|  1|   1|
|  1|   2|
|  1|   3|
|  1|   4|
|  2|   1|
|  2|   2|
+---+----+
```

Comment: How is this solution different from the one I suggested? (You don't have to create an additional column and then drop it)